# Hide other elements in a javascript accordion

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I'm trying to make a simple accordion using html and javascript. Here is my html code :

```
<button class="accordion" id="part_one">Part One</button>
<div class="panel">
</div>

<button class="accordion" id="part_two">Part Two</button>
<div class="panel">
</div>
```

And the script :

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}</script>
```

It works all right. But I was wondering if there is a simple and fast way to hide other parts of the accordion when clicking on one, to make sure there is always only one block displayed. Because as of now, if I click on every buttons I can display everything at the same time, but I don't like it.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: before toggle an active class, remove all active class on .panel

Comment: Here in `onclick` method just remove `active` class from all element contaning `accordion` class.And after that add `active` class to `this` means currently clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the javascript as below.

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
  for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
    setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');
    if (setClasses) {
     this.classList.toggle("active");
     this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
   }
  }
  function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
   for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
   }
  }

 });
```